# How to select a value from combo box in Ext JS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have an EXT JS grid which contains a column having a combobox.

[image]

I want to select a value in this dropdown using javascript, I tried below snippet but it didn't work.

> var comp = Ext.getCmp('grid-accident-voilation');
>   comp.store.getAt(0).data['c1'].setValue('1');

[**EDIT :** Browser Console Log ]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setValue method must be called on the combobox.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue

The combobox is required to be configured with a field on the items in the store that are each item's value. If you simply want to select the first available option, get the first item from the store and set its value on the combobox.

```
var combobox = Ext.getCmp('grid-accident-voilation');
var firstItem = combobox.getStore().getAt(0);
// Optionally, get the value field programmatically.
var valueField = combobox.getInitialConfig('valueField');
combobox.setValue(firstItem.get(valueField));
```

Answer (score 1):

Query for the combobox and use `myComboBox.setValue(1)`.

refer:["ComboBox-method-setValue"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue)

Comment: I tried using snippet provided by you but it is not working. it says setValue is not a function. I am attaching broswer console for the same.

Comment: I am writing a UI Automation script, so i don't have the access to the Ext JS Code. If there something you want to look at pls let me know.